# Passport local mongoose: no username was given error

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

On my frontend login form, I only have input fields `email` and `password`. Passport local expects a `usernameField` name and throws a `[MissingUsernameError: No username was given]`. Is there any way to let passport local not expect a `usernameField`?

Comment: Yes there is. Are you using email in place of username?

Comment: Yes using email instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use email address instead of username, then you need to tell passport that. To do that, kindly see the following code snippet:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email', // this is where you do that
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
       (email, password, done) => {
            User.findOne({
                email: email
            }, (error, user) => {
                if (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Username or password incorrect'
                    });
                }


                // Do other validation/check if any

                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
```

Comment: Got it. Also needed to modify var newUser = new User({username: req.body.email....}); in the signup post route. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, if you don't need a custom user authentication method, you can simply use the User.authenticate() method from passport-local-mongoose. Below implementation will allow reading the value from form input field with name="email" as username when logging in.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, User.authenticate()));
```

Your user schema should still use the keys named "username" and "password", otherwise it will return an error.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

// Add methods from passport-local-mongoose (authenticate, register etc)
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When creating and saving the user to db assign req.body.email to username

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    User.register(
    new User({
        username: req.body.email,
        }),
    req.body.password,
    (err, user) => {
        ...
    }
    )
}
```